# Searching in a JSON object with generated query string

Tags: angularjs, json, lodash

I am trying to search a JSON object in Angular JS using Lo-Dash. The challenge here is that my JSON structure will change dynamically. As a result, my search query string will also have to change.

My JSON is of the format :

```
    {       
            "SERIES": "ABC000123123",
            "SECTOR": "E",
            "INDUSTRY": "N31",
            "DURATION": "1A"    }, 

   {        "SERIES": "ABC000123456",
            "SECTOR": "E",
            "INDUSTRY": "N11",
            "DURATION": "12"    }, 

   {        "SERIES": "ABC000456789",
            "SECTOR": "E",
            "INDUSTRY": "N31",
            "DURATION": "1B"    }
```

My JSON can also be of the following format:

```
{       
            "SERIES": "DEF000321",
            "AREA": "C2",
            "ITEM": "123"    },
{       
            "SERIES": "DEF000321",
            "AREA": "D0",
            "ITEM": "675"    },
```

The keys AREA, ITEM, SECTOR, INDUSTRY, etc will vary.

In all the above cases, only the SERIES field remains constant. 
I need to pass in the key, value pairs of the rest of the attributes to retrieve the SERIES value.

For simplicity sake, my approach using lodash in searching for the above JSON is as follows:

```
_.map(_.filter(JSON_Object, function (value) { 
return (value.AREA == D0) && (value.ITEM == C2) }), 'SERIES');
```

Where I am generating the following string programmatically :

**(value.AREA == 'D0') && (value.ITEM == 'C2')**

This approach does not work.
When I hard code the values, it works fine. Doesn't the other way round when I programmatically generate the query string.

I tried iterating over the list and filtering out one attribute at a time but that would increase the loop count and complexity of my search.

Any suggestions/ work around ? Thanks in advance

Edit: Added screenshot of console :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ0G3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach: https://fiddle.jshell.net/koljada/53esaqLz/1/

```
var JSON_Object = [{
  "SERIES": "ABC000123123",
  "SECTOR": "E",
  "INDUSTRY": "N31",
  "DURATION": "1A"
}, {
  "SERIES": "ABC000123456",
  "SECTOR": "E",
  "INDUSTRY": "N11",
  "DURATION": "12"
}, {
  "SERIES": "ABC000456789",
  "SECTOR": "E",
  "INDUSTRY": "N31",
  "DURATION": "1B"
}];

var query = "(value.SECTOR == 'E') && (value.INDUSTRY == 'N11')";

var result = _(JSON_Object)
  .filter(new Function("value", "return " + query))
  .map('SERIES')
  .value(); // => ["ABC000123456"]
```

Comment: I keep getting an empty array when I use the same function. 
Can you explain the notation
'var result = _(JSON_Object)
  .filter(new Function("value", "return " + query))'

Comment: `new Function("value", "return " + query)` will transposed to `function(value) { return  (value.SECTOR == 'E') && (value.INDUSTRY == 'N11'); }`. So after this it can be used as a predicate in the lodash filter. As you can see, it works on my fiddle. So be careful with your query!

Comment: If you don't like chain notation you can use this: `_.map(_.filter(JSON_Object, new Function("value", "return " + query)),'SERIES');`

Comment: In place of JSON_Object, I am passing a $scope variable  that consists of all my JSON. Is it possible that it might not read the JSON and hence giving me an empty array ? I am debugging in web console, is there a better way?

Comment: Is your $scope variable an array? Because _.filter doesn't work with objects. Could you provide your query and full JSON_Object?

Comment: My JSON might be too big, but here is a part of it 
`[{
 "SERIES_ID": "APU0000701111",
 "AREA_CODE": "0000",
 "ITEM_CODE": "701111"
}, {
 "SERIES_ID": "APU0000702213",
 "AREA_CODE": "0000",
 "ITEM_CODE": "702213"
}, {
 "SERIES_ID": "APU0000702221",
 "AREA_CODE": "0000",
 "ITEM_CODE": "702221"
}, {
 "SERIES_ID": "APU0000702411",
 "AREA_CODE": "0000",
 "ITEM_CODE": "702411"
}]` 

and my generated query is this :
(value.AREA_CODE=='A101') && (value.ITEM_CODE=='72611')

Comment: Your array doesn't contain items with AREA_CODE=='A101' and "ITEM_CODE": "702411". So you query isn't satisfied, that's why your received an empty array.

Comment: These were just the first few records, my actual JSON is HUGE. I am using this in a drop down selection functionality, they do contain the values.

Comment: Could you find the item with AREA_CODE=='A101' and "ITEM_CODE": "702411" in your array?

Comment: Yes, the value exists. I tried with other items too, did'nt work

Comment: Could you try this query `(value.AREA_CODE=='0000') && (value.ITEM_CODE=='701111')`?

Comment: Works now. The string i was generating was having a spacing issue around && operator. Not sure though but adding the space fixed it.

Just a follow up, can I also search with multiple values?
Ex:`(value.AREA_CODE=='0000') && (value.ITEM_CODE=='701111,702222,703333')` ?